# TableSorter - Group plugin

Tags: jquery, grouping, tablesorter

I'm using the following plugin for the jQuery TableSorter to group my rows.

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html

I have everything working as expected the only item I'm not able to get is when the page loads, I'd like to have the table already grouped. I tried to trigger the table header cell's click method but that isn't doing the trick either.

Is there an easy way to set a default grouping with this plugin (hopefully by column index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is define a `sortList` with whichever column you want sorted/grouped (only the first column is grouped); this will initialize the grouping widget ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1829/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    sortList: [ [0, 0] ],
    widgets: ['zebra', 'group']
});
```